# MKReverseGeocoder doesn't call delegates

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to obtain the address for the user location of a `MKMapView`.

Here's my code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = mapview.userLocation.location.coordinate;


MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:userCoordinate] autorelease];

geocoder.delegate = self;
[geocoder start];

locationInstructions.text = @"Finding your location...";

NSLog(@"Started Geocoder");
```

The log gets called fine and if I logged `NSLog(%p,geocorder.delegate);` , it doesn't return `nil`. So there's nothing wrong with my delegate.

Ok now to the delegate methods:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
{
    NSLog(@"Failed!");
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    NSString*str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@",[placemark thoroughfare],[placemark locality],[placemark administrativeArea],[placemark country]];

    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```

None of the delegates ever get called. Why is this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably need to *not* autorelease the geocoder in the first place.

Edit per abitobvious:  Assign the geocoder to an instance variable/property which you then explicitly release when the containing object is dealloc'd.

Comment: wouldn't this throw up an exception and crash the app if it pre-released it?

Comment: Removing `autorelease` did the trick. I don't know why this happens, but it worked! :)

Comment: Although removing autorelease "works", you now have a memory leak.  Instead, follow the pattern in Apple's sample app [CurrentAddress](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing the `MKReverseGeocoderDelegate` in your header?

Comment: Maybe define your geocoder in your header, instead of the scope?

Comment: I've used the same methods in one of my apps, and defining in the header works for me, using @property, @synthesize.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `MKReverseGeocoder *geoCoder` at instance level instead of defining at method level.

I had the same problem and it worked for me as well :)

rohit